# Two abstact classes with constructors, which does base class inherit

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I was asked today in an interview if in C# abstract class "C", is inherited by abstact class "B", and concrete class "A" inherits "B", which constructor is used if "A" doesn't have one, I assumed "C" because parents have priority but not sure.

Comment: *Every* class has a constructor, and constructors aren't inherited (in the way that methods are inherited). If you don't write a constructor yourself, the compiler generates one for you. In this case, the compiler will generate a default constructor for A which calls the default constructor for B.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Yes, except a `static` class, of course,  it has no instance constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That forms a class hierarchy of `A <- B <- C` so *both* are used and called in a specific order.

```
abstract class C
{
    public C()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C()");
    }
}

abstract class B : C
{
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B()");
    }
}

class A : B
{
}

void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
}
```

Output:

```
C()
B()
```

In C# you do not need to explicitly call the base constructor, it will be implicitly called.  So the default constructor `A()` will call `B()` which will call `C()`.

---

> How about if the constructor signatures are different?

If the constructor for `B` or `C` had arguments (no parameter-less constructor available) then the compiler would force you to provide arguments using the [`base`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) keyword.

```
abstract class C
{
    public C(int foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C()");
    }
}

abstract class B : C
{
    public B()
        : base(0 /* foo must be provided */)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B()");
    }
}
```

Comment: can the constructors be different for example 1 take a parameter while 1 doesn't?

Comment: @MilesMorales Yes, look at the `void Main()` method I included.  That is the output of `new A();`

Comment: yes just noticed that sorry, how about if the constructor signatures are different?

Comment: @MilesMorales the compiler would force you to call `base` in the derived class, see my updates